# How to show the name of header files and src files that are included in C/C++ shared library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

For a C/C++ shared library (.so file), how to check all the names of headers and sources that are included in it?

I tried compile the shared library with -g option, and use `readelf -Wl`, but I can only get something like:

> Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
>
> Entry point 0x560
>
> There are 7 program headers, starting at offset 64
>
> Program Headers:
>    Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
>
> LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000754 0x000754 R E 0x200000
>
> LOAD           0x000e70 0x0000000000200e70 0x0000000000200e70 0x0001b0 0x0001b8 RW  0x200000
>
> DYNAMIC        0x000e88 0x0000000000200e88 0x0000000000200e88 0x000150 0x000150 RW  0x8
>
> NOTE           0x0001c8 0x00000000000001c8 0x00000000000001c8 0x000024 0x000024 R   0x4
>
> GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0006a8 0x00000000000006a8 0x00000000000006a8 0x000024 0x000024 R   0x4
>
> GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
>
> GNU_RELRO      0x000e70 0x0000000000200e70 0x0000000000200e70 0x000190 0x000190 R   0x1
>
> Section to Segment mapping:
>
> Segment Sections...
>     00     .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .rela.dyn .init .plt .plt.got .text .fini .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
>
> 01     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss
>
> 02     .dynamic
>
> 03     .note.gnu.build-id
>
> 04     .eh_frame_hdr
>
> 05
>
> 06     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got

Comment: try -s option from readelf, that would give you some idea on what files could be included..

Comment: There is no language C/C++. And libraries are binaries, they are neither C nor C++. They neither include headers (which are source code files, too) nor other sources. It is not clear what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .so won't necessarily even have any of this information unless it was explicitly compiled with "-G".

SUGGESTIONS:

- [How can I know what type of debug info is in an ELF object file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098173/how-can-i-know-what-type-of-debug-info-is-in-an-elf-object-file)

  `objdump -g`

  `objdump -W file.elf`
- [How do I best determine if a binary contains STAB or DWARF debug information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297711/how-do-i-best-determine-if-a-binary-contains-stab-or-dwarf-debug-information)

  `readelf -WS ./a.out | egrep '\.(stab |debug)'`
- [Linux Journal: The ELF Object File Format by Dissection](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1060)
- [Playing with gdb. Reverse engineer your way](https://brundlelab.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/playing-with-gdb-reverse-engineer-your-way/)
- [Debugging formats DWARF and STAB](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debugging/)